# Getting the default argument completion values in PowerShell Core

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to extend the default argument completion i get when pressing CTRL+SPACE, so that the tool-tip line at the very bottom of the MenuComplete will show the help of the actual argument, and not just the basic formatting of how to use the argument.

But i do not want to re-write the whole argument completer that is already in place, but i want to change one value of each of the argument completion result.

The question is: how can i access the default argument completion values for a certain command, or better: how can i access the default argument completer programmatically (and without using the custom argument completer i provide)?

I have found this snipped which will return any custom completers, but i need the default/fallback one:
https://gist.github.com/indented-automation/26c637fb530c4b168e62c72582534f5b

Sample-Code:
I am looking for a way to replace "<GET DEFAULT COMPLETIONS>"

```
Register-ArgumentCompleter -ScriptBlock {
    param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameters)
    $defaultCompletions = <GET DEFAULT COMPLETIONS>
    $defaultCompletions | ForEach-Object {
        $newToolTip = <MY CODE HERE>
        New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult -ArgumentList $_.CompletionText,
            $_.ListItemText,
            $_.ResultType,
            $newToolTip
    }
}
```

Comment: "when pressing CTRL+SPACE" - in what context? Completing command names? Completing a the parameter argument to a specific command? In which case, _what command and parameter_?

Comment: Just any. Really any command or parameter. Not a specific one.

Comment: From the first paragraph in your post it sounds like you want to override the tooltip in input completion results for _commands_ and _parameter names_ - but then you ask how to influence tooltip behavior in an _argument completer_.

Comment: In order to change the tooltip line in the menu completion i need to change the completion result to a different tooltip. This is what the snippet does